# Keras Functional API Multi Input Layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

How do I define a multi input layer using Keras Functional API? Below is an example of the neural network I want to build. There are three input nodes. I want each node to be a 1 dimensional numpy array of different lengths.

Here's what I have so far. Basically I want to define an input layer with multiple input tensors.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, concatenate
from keras.models import Model

x1 = Input(shape =(10,))
x2 = Input(shape =(12,))
x3 = Input(shape =(15,))

input_layer = concatenate([x1,x2,x3])

hidden_layer = Dense(units=4, activation='relu')(input_layer)
prediction = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=prediction)

model.summary()
```

[image: Neural Network]

The code gives the error.

`ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("x1_1:0", shape=(?, 10), dtype=float32) at layer "x1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`

Later when I fit the model I will pass in a list of 1D numpy arrays with the corresponding lengths.

Comment: The funcional API guide describes exactly how to make multiple input models https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/ your problem is that you have to give the inputs (x1, x2, x3), not the layer after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputs must be your `Input()` layers:

```
model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2, x3],outputs=prediction)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
model = Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=prediction)
```

to

```
model = Model(inputs=[x1, x2, x3],outputs=prediction)
```